# ls command does not show app files in Applications or Utilities folders, but Finder shows the apps (macOS Catalina)

Tags: filesystems, ls, macintosh, macos, finder

When I use the "ls -a" command in the /Applications or /Applications/Utilities folders, the only app that shows up is Safari.app in the /Applications folder. However, when I open the same directories in Finder, all of the apps are there and I can launch them and get info and everything.

On a different machine this is not the case, and the ls command finds all of the apps.

I have already tried re-partitioning the boot ssd, wiping all data on the drive, and performing a clean install of MacOS, however the problem persists.

Even in the recovery mode the problem persists. I have verified with a different machine that four apps should appear in the Utilities folder while in recovery mode, however on this machine none do.

At this point I have run out of ideas. If there is an even more factory reset I can do, I'm down to try it.

The most confusing part is that the ls command fails to find the apps whereas terminal has no trouble.

If you want any more specific information let me know and I will try to respond quickly. I apologize if this is the wrong place for this question, but I have never resorted to posting a question before, but this problem has me completely stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not certain, but I believe the current MacOS Finder (v10.15.2) represents the Finder's Application location as a combination of the directories `/Applications` (user downloaded apps) and `/System/Applications` (apps that come with MacOS).  The differences you are seeing between machines could be different versions of MacOS.  Check if you can find your missing applications in `/System/Applications` and `/System/Applications/Utilities`.

Comment: @GracefulRestart So the Applications are showing up (through ls) in the /System versions of the files, but they still won't show up in the /Applications folder. When I do "open ." in the /Applications folder it brings up a finder window which contains all the correct apps, including system apps, and is separate from the /System/Applications folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some testing on a Catalina system, I see more clearly what is happening.

Finder has a ["Smart Folder"](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-or-change-a-smart-folder-on-mac-mchlp2804/mac) for "Applications" which provides the contents of both `/Applications` and `/System/Applications`.  All representations of "Applications" from the Finder use this, including opening `/Applications`.

When you open `/System/Applications`, you are presented with just the contents of that directory.  This should contain the software applications that were installed from the initial installation such as "App Store".

So both `ls /System/Applications` and `open /System/Applications` should have the same content.  While running `ls /Applications` will show you the contents of that directory (normally user installed applications), `open /Applications` will use Finder's special Smart Folder to show all applications available.

Comment: I only have access to one Catalina system at the moment, so before I mark this answer as correct may I ask if you observed the exact same behavior as I have where no default applications show up in the /Applications folder when you run "ls"? Or otherwise a way I might verify what you have said about it being a smart folder and that this is expected behavior and not a glitch? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: My `/Applications` directory only contains applications which I have installed from the App Store, such as Xcode.  I would guess if you have not download or installed any extra applications, that the folder would be empty.

Comment: It seems you are correct, I appreciate your clarification in this matter, and I will be marking your answer as correct. Thanks again!